# I'm trying to insert data into the databse, but I can't do it

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have an error on my website and I reread my text 30 times I can't find the error, can you help me please?

-- The error : --

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in D:\Xamp\htdocs\monoShop\config\commandes.php on line 9

-- The code : --

```
<?php

 function ajouter($image, $nom, $prix, $desc)
{
   if(require("connexion.php"))
   {
     $req = $access->prepare("INSERT INTO produits (image, nom, prix, description) VALUES ('$image', '$nom', $prix, '$desc')");

     $req->execute(array($image, $nom, $prix, $desc));

     $req->closeCursor();
   }
}

function afficher()
{
    if(require("connexion.php"))
    {
        $req=$access->prepare("SELECT * FROM produits ORDER BY id DESC");

        $req->execute();

        $data = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $data;

        $req->closeCursor();
    }
}

function supprimer($id)
{
    if(require("connexion.php"))
    {
        $req=$access->prepare("DELETE FROM produits WHERE id=?");

        $req->execute(array($id));

        $req->closeCursor();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You try to bind four values in `execute()`, but you query has zero tokens.

Comment: Try: `"INSERT INTO produits (image, nom, prix, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"`

Comment: Thanks it's working, I love you <3

Answer (score 0):

```
$req = $access->prepare("INSERT INTO produits (image, nom, prix, description) VALUES (:image', :nom', :prix, :desc')")
$req->bindValue("image", $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindValue("nom", $nom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindValue("prix", $prix, PDO::PARAM_STR); // ou tu met PDO::PARAM_INT si c'est un nombre
$req->bindValue("desc", $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
```

This makes it easier to add values ​​with the bindValue which replaces the word you put with the variable. It adds security too